# Can't Load Phalcon Extension On Windows with Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, window, phalcon

Currently I am using

a. PHP Version : 7.4.4

b. Web Server: XAMPP

c. Architecture : x64

d. OS: Windows 10

**What I've Tried**

a. I downloaded phalcon_x64_vc15_php7.4_4.0.5+5010.zip from Phalcon Repo

b. Then I added extracted the file and copied php_phalcon.dll to C:\xampp\php\ext

c. When to php.ini and added this following line extension=php_phalcon.dll

d. Restarted my Xampp server

**Output**

a.Checked my phpinfo() , but phalcon extension is missing.

b.Checked my apache_error_log , got the following error

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'phalcon' because required module 'psr' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phalcon requires the PSR extension.

You can download it : 
https://pecl.php.net/package/psr

If you need more info about psr : https://github.com/jbboehr/php-psr

And add it to Xampp like you did with php_phalcon.dll

Comment: Thanks @Inther, this is the correct answer, it has solved my problem. I will Post my solution above, so that everyone else can refer.

Answer (score 1):

@Inther has the correct Solution. I will post my complete steps to solve this problem.

a. Go to https://pecl.php.net/package/psr to download PSR.

b. If you are using APACHE choose thread safe download , if you are using NGINX then choose the non thread safe version . Since I am using PHP 7.4 x64 and apache, I choosed **7.4 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64** download.

c. Extracted the downloaded zip folder and copied php_psr.dll file to C:\xampp\php\ext

d. GO to php.ini and added this following line extension=php_psr.dll

e. Restarted xampp apache server.

f. Phalcon should appear in phpinfo();